# PLS-00323 in Oracle: subprogram must be defined in the package body

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a total newbie in SQL.

I try to define a package with function

The specs:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MBA.OSA
AS
  FUNCTION FUNC_OSA 
  (inp_SKU in number, func_store_id in number, func_start_date in DATE, func_end_date in DATE)
  RETURN NUMBER;
END OSA;
```

And the body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MBA.OSA as
function FUNC_OSA 

return number
IS 
p_OSA NUMBER;
func_start_date date;
func_end_date date;
inp_SKU number;
func_store_id number;

BEGIN
with period_len as (
select (func_end_date - func_start_date) len_per from dual
),
OSA_ as (
select dm.SKU,
      dm.store_id,
     ROUND(count(distinct dm.TRAN_DATE) / (select len_per from period_len) * 100,0) OSA
    --into OSA
    from datamarts.SALES_DETAIL_DM dm
    where SKU = inp_SKU
    AND TRAN_DATE between func_start_date and func_end_date
    AND dm.store_id = func_store_id
group by dm.SKU, dm.store_id
)
select OSA into p_OSA from OSA_;

RETURN p_OSA;
END FUNC_OSA;

END OSA;
```

But I get the error

> PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'FUNC_OSA' is declared in a package
>   specification and must be defined in the package body

I tried to declare it, but I don't succeed.

Comment: Try adding the params to the function in the body also.

Comment: @sgalem you mean  function FUNC_OSA (inp_SKU in number, func_store_id in number, func_start_date in DATE, func_end_date in DATE)? I tried, it doesn't help, only causes more errors

Comment: It lead to more errors because you left the variables that are now params in the function declaration part, no?

Comment: @Katya sometimes "more errors" is progress, because it means you have dealt with the first error and moved on to the next issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your function as in package spec.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MBA.OSA as

function FUNC_OSA  (inp_SKU in number, func_store_id in number, func_start_date in DATE, func_end_date in DATE) RETURN NUMBER
IS 
p_OSA NUMBER;
BEGIN
with period_len as (
select (func_end_date - func_start_date) len_per from dual
),
OSA_ as (
select dm.SKU,
      dm.store_id,
     ROUND(count(distinct dm.TRAN_DATE) / (select len_per from period_len) * 100,0) OSA
    --into OSA
    from datamarts.SALES_DETAIL_DM dm
    where SKU = inp_SKU
    AND TRAN_DATE between func_start_date and func_end_date
    AND dm.store_id = func_store_id
group by dm.SKU, dm.store_id
)
select OSA into p_OSA from OSA_;

RETURN p_OSA;
END FUNC_OSA;

END OSA;
```

Comment: @unus-haznedar Thank you!! But I also have a mistake that name of the package and name of schema must match with editing object (function FUNC_OSA, apparently). Could you please also resolve this?

Comment: I dont get it, what is the problem exactly? You created spec and body in MBA schema.

Comment: @YUNUS_HAZNEDAR I also don't  get it. But the package doen't compile due to the error described above

Comment: Could you please write exact message with Oracle code?